# ZeroClipboard not working on first click

Tags: javascript, onclick, copy, clipboard, zeroclipboard

Flow summary:
I wrote a jsp page, and a js file. The jsp including form with a clickable area. When user clicks there, the js adds button with onclick method to the jsp and if the user clicks on that button, some text should be copied to the clipboard.

JS adding the button to jsp:

```
<button id="copyToClipboard" title="Copy to clipboard" type="button" onclick="shareTransaction($(this))"></button>
```

JS onclick:

```
function shareTransaction(e) {
    $('#copyToClipboard').attr('data-clipboard-text',$(location).attr('protocol')+'//'+$(location).attr('host')+'/goblin/'+result);
    var zeroClipboard = new ZeroClipboard($("#copyToClipboard"));
}
```

In the first click, nothing happends. In the second click- the text copied successfully.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize the ZeroClipboard object before clicking the button.

sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.0.0/ZeroClipboard.Core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.0.0/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initZc(){
                var button = $("button");
                console.log(button)
                var clip = new ZeroClipboard(button);
                clip.on( 'ready', function(event) {
                    clip.on('copy', function(event) {
                        event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', "working");
                    });
                } );
            };
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document.body).append($("<button>click to copy</button>"));
                initZc();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working. You can't do initialization before creating the button. When initialize ZeroClipboard, it looks for element id (#copyToClipboard) which is not created yet

Comment: Using $(document).ready makes no difference in this case because the button creates in the JavaScript file. not in the html file (jsp).

Comment: Dude, I changed the sample code, try it. ( don't try it as a local file with url file:///.... ) it won't work in chrome, put it on a server.